# Why is only fender with surface rust? What to do about it?

Tags: paint, rust, body

I have a 2015 Toyota Yaris. I've owned it since it was new. There is a small amount of surface rust on my left rear fender:

[image]

The right side, on the other hand, is perfect:

[image]

Why would there be surface rust only on one side? What should I do about this surface rust?

(I'm in the US, left hand drive, if that matters)

Comment: Modern cars don't usually rust through the paintwork in 8 years, unless there has been a repair, when the paintwork will almost always be inferior to the factory finish. But as you had the car from new, perhaps the *dealer* somehow scraped it. One thing to do is to examine the paintwork and its reflections from different directions and in different light to see if you can spot any imperfections. I bought one used car on bright sunny day, looked at the panels and paintwork carefully but it was two weeks before I noticed a colour difference of a rear door, which was noticable only in poor light.

Answer (score 1):

Scratch out bubbled paint with a nail or other implement.  Clean with [CLR Pro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G9JMTS2), treat with [rust neutralizer/plasticizer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001AZLA08), then touch-up with [Dr. ColorChip](https://drcolorchip.com/) matched for your vehicle.